# in chrome extension how can i have multiple groups of radio buttons in context menu

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I know how to make radio buttons in context menu using chrome extension in chrome. But what i dont get is how would i group them. So certain radio elements act as one set and only one of them can get selected. But doing so doesn't affect elements in other sets(group).

All you get to define when creating an item in context menu is its id, type, and parent and other stuff that become even more irrelevant.

I'd appreciate help a lot. thanks.

The sample code i am reading from is here : 
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/contextMenus/event_page/sample.js

Api reference for context menu: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus.html#method-create

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consecutive radio buttons will belong to the same group. If there is any other type of menu item in between, radio buttons will belong to different groups. For instance:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({type:'radio', title:'group1 r1'});
chrome.contextMenus.create({type:'radio', title:'group1 r2'});
chrome.contextMenus.create({type:'separator'});
chrome.contextMenus.create({type:'radio', title:'group2 r1'});
chrome.contextMenus.create({type:'radio', title:'group2 r2'});
```

Comment: -__- how did i miss separator.  This should be mentioned there more clearly. Nice answer.

Comment: If you're creating menus from an event page, Chrome requires you to include an `id`, even for separators, which is surprising.